# How to perform the Action (or) Send Event Slowly in Auto Hot Key

Tags: autohotkey

When I run my script I want the send event to be performed slowly step-by-step. Below is my running code :

NOTE: I had tried using Set Key Delay and SetControlDelay but doesn't work :(

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent

Run,Desk.cpl
SetTimer, Check, 1000
return

Check:

IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
SetKeyDelay, 0
SendEvent {Click 678, 368}

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
SendEvent {Click 212, 67}

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
SetControlDelay, 20
SendEvent {Click 88, 362}


IfWinNotExist, ahk_class CabinetWClass
{
ExitApp
return
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem with your script? Please explain what your script does wrongly, and what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [SetMouseDelay](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetMouseDelay.htm). Increase the numbers and test out what is the best timing for you.

```
#SingleInstance force
#Persistent

Run,Desk.cpl
SetTimer, Check, 1000
return

Check:

IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
SetMouseDelay, 0
SendEvent {Click 678, 368}

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
SendEvent {Click 212, 67}

IfWinActive, ahk_class #32770
SetMouseDelay, 20
SendEvent {Click 88, 362}


IfWinNotExist, ahk_class CabinetWClass
{
ExitApp
return
}
```